# Is -using ReferenceProperty in Google App Engine datastore- reasonable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Story(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)

story = db.get(story_key)
author_name = story.author.name

author = db.get(author_key)
stories_by_author = author.story_set.get()
```

As is known; using ReferenceProperty is good solution for data relationship as exampled above.
So;
For example, we have a large amout of row in our "Author" and "Story" entities(tables). And after many years we deleted "Author" entity or replaced  name propery to another name. 
Naturally; our app sholud throw error.
Can this situation (managing code) reasonable or  is performing relationships manually good?  Is there any alternative model for this case?

Answer (score 0):

That's the tool provided by the datastore.  If you want something more robust, you can build a class with destructors that always check their ReferenceProperties and clean them up.

This is kinda like asking whether pointers are a bad thing because you can leak memory and leave dangling pointers.  Yes they are, but on some languages, that's the basic tool available.  If you want something safer, build a wrapper around it.  Or use another language (like Cloud SQL).